# Ping until success check in Python, then break assign variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, ping, break

I have the following piece of Python 2.7 code:

```
def getGateway():
""" Use the configuration to determine valid gateway
    If more GWs are present, one will be chosen by random.choice
"""
localServer = ThisLocalServer(log=LOG)
gw=localServer.getRandomAgentGateway()
print "See if its a string %s - %s" % (gw,type(gw))
candidate = "gw"
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + candidate)
if response == 0:
    print candidate, 'is up!'
    return gw
else:
    print candidate, 'is down we need a new gatewuy'
```

The use case is as follows:
My software determines an IP using getRandomAgentGateway. Unfortunately it is not as inteligent as i want it to be and sometimes the result is an unreachable IP. I want to build in a ping check that will :
A) Get one IP ( there are only two in the list ) using the already built in getRandomAgentGateway
B) Ping the IP
C) Make sure this IP is reachable , if yes - deliver a reachable IP, break out of the loop and execute "return gw" , if not - stay in the loop and call "getRandomAgentGateway()" again until it finds a reachable IP

I cannot modify getRandomAgentGateway, so i would like to build the ping check here. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an error in your logic.

```
candidate = "gw"
```

seems to be doing the wrong thing. What you need is probably

```
if isinstance(gw,str):
    # do whatever
```

Actually, why getRandomAgentGateway will return other answer than an str?

Finally, for this to work you probably should try more than one time, writing something like:

```
def teste():
    max_number_of_tries = 2
    current_try = 0
    while current_try < max_number_of_tries: 
        gw=getRandomAgentGateway()
        if isinstance(gw,str): 
            response = os.system("ping " + gw)
            if response == 0:
                print( gw, 'is up!')
                return gw
            else:
                print( gw, 'is down we need a new gatewuy, trying again')
        current_try += 1
        print ( "Too much tries" )
```

Comment: getRandomAgentGateway  is always a string. I just added this for debugging purposes to make sure.

Comment: How can I add logging to make sure the output is kept for debugging?

Comment: You could, or actually should, use the logging module.

Comment: I cant seem to get this right, sorry but i am rather new to this. Is there a way you could paste the whole function ? Starting from def getGateway():

Comment: I just edit gw is str , because it was wrong, to isinstance(gw,str).
Also beware that "Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges." Try your command ping in command line.

Comment: Ok, you have your function now, it ran in Python 3, you should only take the "(" and ")" out of your prints

Comment: Many thanks. Now I am on the right track. I can see ping working, but the string I actually get instead from getRandomAgentGateway instead of an IP (10.10.10.10) is IP:PORT (10.10.10.10:1000), so it throws back: ping unknown host 10.10.10.10:1000 and I just need to cut the "1000" part :) .

Comment: I used slice to get rid of the port. Works like a charm now.